# Which languages are used in Hadoop Implementation?

Tags: hadoop

I am an academician, studying Hadoop for presentations in class. I need information about following two aspects:
1. Which languages are popularly used in Hadoop implementation by Industry?
2. Where can I get the real problems and data sets used in industry?

Thanking you in anticipation.
Regards
Meenal

Answer (score 0):

1) Hadoop Open Source Software Framework wholely written in Java 
2) You can find some publicly available Data Sets in below links 
http://hadoopilluminated.com/hadoop_illuminated/Public_Bigdata_Sets.html 
http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20140707/ 
https://aws.amazon.com/datasets